# Favorites bar icon is black

Tags: icons, favorites

Running 22.04 LTS. When I plug in an external Seagate HD, the icon shows a USB symbol for a moment and then the icon turns black. If I right click and unmount the drive and then mount it again, same problem. On a different computer running the same Ubuntu version, the icon shows correctly. Is there a way to fix this? I don't care what the icon looks like as long as it's other than black.

`inxi -G` returned the following values:

```
Graphics: Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor 
Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel Device-2: NVIDIA GK107M 
[GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition] 
driver: nouveau v: kernel Device-3: Apple FaceTime HD 
Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: 
  Xwayland v: 22.1.1 compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.2 
  driver: gpu: i915,nouveau 
  resolution: 1: 1440x900~60Hz 2: 1440x900~60Hz 
OpenGL: renderer: NVE7 v: 4.3 Mesa 22.0.5
```

Comment: Rather vague, your infos. So that it might be either your graphics card, or you are running Xorg instead of wayland. We don't know. Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) help you to refine your question? `inxi -G` should shed some light on your hardware.

Comment: I'm new at this, so bear with the vagueness if you will. inxi returned this:
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition] driver: nouveau
    v: kernel
  Device-3: Apple FaceTime HD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.2 driver: gpu: i915,nouveau resolution:
    1: 1440x900~60Hz 2: 1440x900~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVE7 v: 4.3 Mesa 22.0.5

Comment: Do not expect readers to read the comments. Better to paste it into your question next time (I've done it for you this time ;-). Install the proprietary  Nvida drivers. (Just go to Activities and type `driver`)